# Managing Process Forks in C in Linux/Unix

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

I am wondering how you can get a child process to wait to execute a statement after it's parent does a particular thing.

My needs are fairly simple, I just need to spawn the child process with fork, have the parent write something to a file, then have the child write something to the file, then they both finish executing their separate commands.

I've only learned about using wait() and waitpid() to have child processes execute first, then have the parent execute, but that obviously won't work here.

Any ideas?

Help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Here's a quick overview of the various methods for communicating between process Linux provides: http://tldp.org/LDP/tlk/ipc/ipc.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `pipe()` between the parent and child. The parent writes to the child via the pipe after the parent has finished writing to the file.

Comment: For clarity's sake, I'd add that the parent needs only write one byte to the pipe, and it doesn't matter what that byte is.  The child waits for read() on the pipe to come back before it does anything else, but it doesn't need to *do* anything with the data sent.  This can be expanded to a token-passing scheme to coordinate many child processes, although there are subtleties: see for instance http://mad-scientist.net/make/jobserver.html

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you have the parent do its writing before spawning the child?

If that won't work, you really should think about whether `fork` is the right tool for the job I've seen a lot of `fork`-related questions here, probably as a result of some old-timer professor with his head buried in the 70s not being aware that POSIX threads are the tool for most such jobs. Really the **only** legitimate uses for `fork` are running external programs (but `posix_spawn` is a better interface for doing so) and handing off heavy-weight client connections (like ssh sessions) to a completely new process that needs to adjust its privileges and isolate itself from other sessions for security purposes.

Comment: For a discussion of `posix_spawn()` vs `fork()`/`exec()`, check http://old.nabble.com/fork()%2Bexec()-vs-posix_spawn()-td19224020.html

Comment: Note that on systems without `posix_spawn`, it's trivial to implement it as a library routine on top of `fork` (or better yet, on top of `vfork` if it's available).

Comment: @R I was under the impression that, at least for Linux, the startup overhead for `fork()` has been optimized to next to nothing allowing you to do simple tasks similar to the OP's without having to worry about all the pitfalls that come with threads like thread-safe functions, mutex/semaphore handling and deadlocks.

Comment: The `fork` itself has very low cost, but communication will be much more costly. Unless you setup shared memory, all communication will have to go through the kernel. With threads, the kernel will never be involved in communication between threads except in the case of waiting or contention. As for the complexity of concurrency, deadlocks, etc., the same issues apply with synchronizing separate processes. File locks, ipc semaphores, etc. can all lead to deadlocks if used incorrectly.

Comment: I see sending all communication through the kernel as an *advantage* of forked processes relative to threads. You have to define your IPC precisely, which means it's easier to find and deal with all the places you could have concurrency problems. You also get memory protection for free.  The only advantage threads have is less communication overhead, and there are clean ways to reduce it (explicit shared memory segments, for instance) without giving up the advantage of greater isolation. Personally I think threads are an optimization to use only after exhausting all other alternatives.

Comment: @Zack: I think there are definitely right and wrong ways to use threads, and many of the wrong ways have to do with things that are already wrong, like global variables. But I've also seen a lot of nonsensical use of `fork` for concurrent computation on SO lately. I would go so far as to say `fork` is useless for most concurrency. It's useful for completely independent operations like password cracking or SETI, and of course for safety and isolation of sessions, but not for parallelizing small jobs like single image processing.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want extra safety and isolation on your small processing jobs?  I'd build that with fork(), no question, and I'd expect it to be plenty fast enough.

Comment: Some of the examples I've seen creep up on SO lately include things like forking a new process for each line of inverting an image. `fork` may be well-optimized, but unless your image is more than a million pixels wide, there's no way that will be faster than just doing everything all in one process...not to mention there's probably the extra step of copying it to the shared memory region. With threads, if you broke up the image more reasonably than single lines, there *might* be a benefit to processing it in parallel.

Comment: Oh, yes, I see what you mean now.  I guess my claim is that for any parallelizable computational task, when partitioned correctly, you can get nearly the same speedup with processes as with threads.  I say "computational" because sometimes you're trying to parallelize I/O requests, and the OS's async I/O primitives do not cover the territory, at which point threads are pretty much your only option.

Comment: I guess what it comes down to is that if you have a task that can be broken up into many long-running, non-synchronized or barely-synchronized parts, using separate processes to parallelize it is a very good idea, especially since the work distribution and synchronization methods you're likely to use will easily adapt to splitting the task across independent machines. But for parallel/async IO, or parallelizing time-sensitive operations like realtime A/V processing, simulations, games, hardware emulation, interactive image editing, etc. threads are a much better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Use a signal. Choose one of the utility signals, and have the parent send it to the child after the write.